# Resizing images to fit in a container perfectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I searched this question all over on here and found a couple of examples and I tried one in particular, but it is not working at all like I am wanting it to.

I have set the container's height to 600px and it is not even coming close. I am sure it is due to my image width only being 33%, but is there a way to get these taller at all or am I stuck with the height only being this tall?

I don't get why the far right image isn't even going to the top of the container. I at least want that to be like that.

Is there anyway to adjust the height for these images or will that pull it completely out of proportion?

[image]

```js
$(window).load(function(){
 $('.home-img-block').find('img').each(function(){
  var imgClass = (this.width/this.height > 1) ? 'wide' : 'tall';
  $(this).addClass(imgClass);
 })
})
```

```css
#home-img-blocks {
 width: 100%;
 height: 600px;
}
/*#home-img-blocks-container {
 border: 1px solid black;
}*/
.home-img-block {
 width: 33%;
 height: 100%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 display: inline-block;
}
.home-img-block img.wide {
 max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
.home-img-block img.tall {
 max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home-img-blocks">
 <div class="home-img-block"><img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test1.jpg"></div><div class="home-img-block"><img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test2.jpg">
   </div><div class="home-img-block"><img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test3.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you expecting this: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/w3aerp1L/ ?

Comment: Yes, just so the images cover the entire height of the container, without getting out of proportion or gutting out the image.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Paul, If so, then I am closing this question. There is nothing much to be answered..

Comment: @RayonDabre What do you mean? I am not getting what you are?? Even when I just tried your code, I have the same result as before.

Answer (score 0):

Following way you can cover whole height of your container. Remove `max-width` from image and give `vertical-align:top` and `overflow: hidden;` to container.

But not that, it will cut your image because it will not maintain aspect ratio as height is so high and width small.

```js
$(window).load(function(){
 $('.home-img-block').find('img').each(function(){
  var imgClass = (this.width/this.height > 1) ? 'wide' : 'tall';
  $(this).addClass(imgClass);
 })
})
```

```css
#home-img-blocks {
 width: 100%;
 height: 600px;
}
/*#home-img-blocks-container {
 border: 1px solid black;
}*/
.home-img-block {
 width: 33%;
 height: 100%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.home-img-block img.wide {
 
    max-height: 100%;
 
}
.home-img-block img.tall {
 max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home-img-blocks">
 <div class="home-img-block"><img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test1.jpg"></div><div class="home-img-block"><img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test2.jpg">
   </div><div class="home-img-block"><img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test3.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am still wanting to images to be proportionate if possible.

Comment: @Paul How  you want proportionate ? There is height to high and and width small of container so, it will not maintain ratio.

Comment: Can you give picture/snapshot of your expected output?

Comment: I don't get how rayon's fiddle got the images to cover the entire div height then?  jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/w3aerp1L  .. I even tried the code and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have set your height to auto for the pics so if your rightmost picture has different original size than the other 2 that might be the problem. You can try to add an id for the last picture and than work with it specifically increasing its height. You can also try to use bootstrap it is incredible useful for dividing you screen on equal parts.

Answer (score 0):

```
#home-img-blocks {
    font-size: 0;
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
}
/*#home-img-blocks-container {
    border: 1px solid black;
}*/
.home-img-block {
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 33.33%;
}
.home-img-block img.wide {
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -20%;
    width: auto;
}
.home-img-block img.tall {
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -50%;
}


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<div id="home-img-blocks">
    <div class="home-img-block">
        <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="home-img-block">
        <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="home-img-block">
        <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test3.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

You can try the above code, It will work out for all normal desktop screen perfectly..

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div id="home-img-blocks">

      <div class="home-img-block">
    <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test1.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="home-img-block">
    <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test2.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="home-img-block">
    <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test3.jpg">
  </div>

</div>
```

css

```
#home-img-blocks {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:center;
  /* flex-wrap:wrap; */ /* turn this on if you want the images to wrap on smaller browsers */
  width:auto; /* calculates to 1156px wide */
    height: 600px;
}

.home-img-block {
    flex:0 0 896px; /* round down of narrowest image at 600px height */
  overflow:hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.home-img-block img {
    max-height:100%;
}
```

js

no need

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrdELK

Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Support

http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Do extra code specifically for ie11 if need be (#home-img-blocks -> display:table / .home-img-block --> display:table-cell) but look in ie11 first, because it may be fine.